# Find the texts in Dynamic Range in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VBA application that will find the text that I have entered in a certain range (Should be dynamic, in order for me to input more in the future). With that the entered texts in the range will look for the words in another sheet column:

Example:

[image: Words to look for]

And it will look for the words inputted in another sheet.

```
Dim Main as Worksheet
Set Main = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Raw2 as Worksheet
Set Raw2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 

LookFor = Main.Range(D8:100)
Fruits = Raw2.Range("G" & Raw2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 
For e = lastRow To 2 Step -1 

value = Raw2.Cells(e, 7).value

If Instr(value, LookFor) = 0 _
Then

Raw2.Rows(e).Delete
```

Honestly I am not sure how to proceed. And the mentioned code is just experiment. Desired output is to delete anything in sheet2 except for the rows that contain the words that I have inputted in the "Look for the words". Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What is your code so far? Can you describe the desired output?

Comment: @Sevpoint As you can see, by entering your code as a comment, it is difficult to follow.  Please edit your original question and add the code in that edit, properly formatted. Also, please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There you go. I have edited it @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
Sub Sevpoint()

Dim Main As Worksheet
Set Main = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Raw2 As Worksheet
Set Raw2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim LooKFoR() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Double
Dim i As Double
Dim j As Double
Dim ValRow As String
Dim DelRow As Boolean

LooKFoR = Main.Range(Main.Range("G8"), Main.Range("G" & Main.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

LastRow = Raw2.Range("G" & Raw2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    ValRow = Raw2.Cells(i, 7).Value
    DelRow = True
    'MsgBox UBound(LooKFoR, 1)
    For j = LBound(LooKFoR, 1) To UBound(LooKFoR, 1)
        If LCase(ValRow)<>LCase(LooKFoR(j, 1)) Then
        Else
            DelRow = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If DelRow Then Raw2.Rows(i).Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tested it somehow it doesn't work. Though it doesn't give any errors. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks!

Comment: @Sevpoint : Where are located your words and the data you want to delete (sheet + address in sheet)?

Comment: The words that needs to be searched is from Main sheet. And the data that I want to delete is in Sheet 2 (Raw2). The Column that it will search is in the Sheet 2 (Raw2), Column G. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sevpoint : Try the edit! ;) I've added a message to display the numbers of words, to help debug (I've considered they are starting in G8 on Main)

Comment: Hello @R3uk it prompts me a number 4 since I have inputted 4 fruits. Apple, Banana, Guava, Kiwi. This is what Sheet 2 (Raw2) Contains: Apple, Banana, Guava, Kiwi, grapes, orange. Somehow, it doesn't delete the row of grapes and orange in Sheet 2 (Raw2) G column. The code almost works. :)

Comment: Super! It answered my question! Really helped me a lot! :) Thank you very much!

Comment: What would I do if I want it to be not really the exact keywords? Like for example, the keyword to look for is "Apple" and on the list there is "Apples" in Sheet 2 (Raw2) . I would want the "apples" not to be deleted since it contains "apple".

Comment: Use `Instr()` function, you will find the syntax easily googling VBA instr! ;)